Getting an error with a union in SSIS, "The Metadata for union does not match the metadata for the associated output column." Any ideas?
I am working with SSIS in Visual Studio 2019, and I am trying to do something fairly simple. In the data flow I load data from two flat files (basically, half the data set in each file), union them together, then after doing a few simple derivations and a lookup, I save the data to the database. The Data Flow looks like this:

Now, when I had this with a single input file, it worked perfectly. This error only cropped up when I split the data between two data files and tried to union them together.
Double-clicking on the union I see that all input from the second file is set to ignore. When I try to set the input 2 to map CityName to CityName, I get the following error.

I have no idea what this error means, and I haven't found anything on point in my searches. Does anyone have any insight to offer?

I decided to ditch union and go for merge. Since the data sources aren't sorted, I had to do that, but the merge worked. Still don't know why the Union didn't work, but at least I've got it running.

And for the record, I'm still interested in learning what the error with the union was.
